# How to calculate a probability vector and an observation count vector for a range of bins?

Tags: octave, statistical-test

I want to test the hypothesis whether some 30 occurrences should fit a Poisson distribution.

```
#GNU Octave
X = [8 0 0 1 3 4 0 2 12 5 1 8 0 2 0 1 9 3 4 5 3 3 4 7 4 0 1 2 1 2]; #30 observations
bins = {0, 1, [2:3], [4:5], [6:20]}; #each bin can be single value or multiple values
```

I am trying to use Pearson's chi-square statistics here and coded the below function. I want a Poisson vector to contain corresponding Poisson probabilities for each bin and count the observations for each bin. I feel the loop is rather redundant and ugly. Can you please let me know how can I re-factor the function without the loop and make the whole calculation cleaner and more vectorized?

```
function result= poissonGoodnessOfFit(bins, observed)
  
  assert(iscell(bins), "bins should be a cell array");
  assert(all(cellfun("ismatrix", bins)) == 1, "bin entries either scalars or matrices");
  assert(ismatrix(observed) && rows(observed) == 1, "observed data should be a 1xn matrix");
  
  lambda_head = mean(observed); #poisson lambda parameter estimate
  k = length(bins); #number of bin groups
  n = length(observed); #number of observations
  
  poisson_probability = []; #variable for poisson probability for each bin
  observations = []; #variable for observation counts for each bin
  
  for i=1:k
    if isscalar(bins{1,i}) #this bin contains a single value
      poisson_probability(1,i) = poisspdf(bins{1, i}, lambda_head);
      observations(1, i) = histc(observed, bins{1, i});
    else  #this bin contains a range of values
      inner_bins = bins{1, i}; #retrieve the range
      inner_bins_k = length(inner_bins); #number of values inside
      inner_poisson_probability = []; #variable to store individual probability of each value inside this bin
      inner_observations = []; #variable to store observation counts of each value inside this bin
      for j=1:inner_bins_k
        inner_poisson_probability(1,j) = poisspdf(inner_bins(1, j), lambda_head);
        inner_observations(1, j) = histc(observed, inner_bins(1, j)); 
      endfor
      poisson_probability(1, i) = sum(inner_poisson_probability, 2); #assign over the sum of all inner probabilities
      observations(1, i) = sum(inner_observations, 2); #assign over the sum of all inner observation counts
    endif
  endfor
  
  expected = n .* poisson_probability; #expected observations if indeed poisson using lambda_head
  chisq = sum((observations - expected).^2 ./ expected, 2); #Pearson Chi-Square statistics 
  pvalue = 1 - chi2cdf(chisq, k-1-1); 
  result = struct("actual", observations, "expected", expected, "chi2", chisq, "pvalue", pvalue); 
  
  return;
  
endfunction
```

Comment: You are milliseconds away from one of the usual suspects showing up and removing the matlab tag from your post. If you _do_ care about matlab compatibility as implied by your post title, please make an effort to write in matlab-compatible code.

Comment: @ABC: Removing the MATLAB tag was meant to help you and prevent annoyance from a potential answerer. I’ve seen this many times, where a MATLAB answer is given and the OP is “oh, but I actually use Octave and this doesn’t work there.” Also, the code you posted would produce lots of syntax errors if you try running it in MATLAB. Just because Octave is based on MATLAB syntax, and it is possible to write code using only a common subset of  the two packages, doesn’t mean that the two are exchangeable.

Comment: @ABCAnalytics I'm often annoyed at the matlab tag removal too, since if someone asks (implicitly or explicitly) for a matlab-compatible answer, then my view is that this should be honoured, or at least explain why matlab compatibility would not be a good idea. Simply removing the matlab tag can be annoying and does a disservice to good questions which could have also been useful to a matlab audience. However, it's equally annoying when the remover is absolutely right, like Cris in this case. If you've made no effort to write in a matlab compatible subset, then this really isn't matlab-related.

Comment: Think of it another way. If you tagged a question "c or c++" and then your example involved code which is unsupported in c, that would be very annoying to c users who wasted their time reading the question. Even more so if they bothered to provide you with a c-compatible answer and you replied with "oh I need to use a c++ class thanks".

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things worth noting in the code.

First, the 'scalar' case in your if block is actually identical to your 'range' case, since a scalar is simply a range of 1 element. So no special treatment is needed for it.

Second, you don't need to create such explicit subranges, your bin groups seem to be amenable to being used as indices into a larger result (as long as you add 1 to convert from 0-indexed to 1-indexed indices).

Therefore my approach would be to calculate the expected and observed numbers over the entire domain of interest (as inferred from your bin groups), and then use the bin groups themselves as 1-indices to obtain the desired subgroups, summing accordingly.

Here's an example code, written in the octave/matlab compatible subset of both languges:

```
function Result = poissonGoodnessOfFit( BinGroups, Observations )
% POISSONGOODNESSOFFIT( BinGroups, Observations) calculates the [... etc, etc.]

  pkg load statistics; % only needed in octave; for matlab buy statistics toolbox.
  assert( iscell( BinGroups ),   'Bins should be a cell array' );
  assert( all( cellfun( @ismatrix, BinGroups ) ) == 1,   'Bin entries either scalars or matrices' );
  assert( ismatrix( Observations ) && rows( Observations ) == 1,   'Observed data should be a 1xn matrix' );

% Define helpful variables
  RangeMin       = min( cellfun( @min, BinGroups ) );
  RangeMax       = max( cellfun( @max, BinGroups ) );
  Domain         = RangeMin : RangeMax;
  LambdaEstimate = mean( Observations );
  NBinGroups     = length( BinGroups );
  NObservations  = length( Observations );

% Get expected and observed numbers per 'bin' (i.e. discrete value) over the *entire* domain.
  Expected_Domain = NObservations * poisspdf( Domain, LambdaEstimate );
  Observed_Domain = histc( Observations, Domain );

% Apply BinGroup values as indices
  Expected_byBinGroup = cellfun( @(c) sum( Expected_Domain(c+1) ), BinGroups );
  Observed_byBinGroup = cellfun( @(c) sum( Observed_Domain(c+1) ), BinGroups );

% Perform a Chi-Square test on the Bin-wise Expected and Observed outputs
  O = Observed_byBinGroup; E = Expected_byBinGroup ; df = NBinGroups - 1 - 1;
  ChiSquareTestStatistic = sum( (O - E) .^ 2 ./ E );

  PValue = 1 - chi2cdf( ChiSquareTestStatistic, df );
  Result = struct( 'actual', O, 'expected', E, 'chi2', ChiSquareTestStatistic, 'pvalue', PValue );
end
```

Running with your example gives:

```
X = [8 0 0 1 3 4 0 2 12 5 1 8 0 2 0 1 9 3 4 5 3 3 4 7 4 0 1 2 1 2]; % 30 observations
bins = {0, 1, [2:3], [4:5], [6:20]}; % each bin can be single value or multiple values
Result = poissonGoodnessOfFit( bins, X )
% Result =
%  scalar structure containing the fields:
%    actual   = 6         5        8          6         5
%    expected = 1.2643    4.0037   13.0304    8.6522    3.0493
%    chi2 =  21.989
%    pvalue =  0.000065574
```

A general comment about the code; it is always preferable to write self-explainable code, rather than code that does not make sense by itself in the absence of a comment. Comments generally should only be used to explain the 'why', rather than the 'how'.

Comment: Thanks. Let me spend some time to study your code. Coming from a Java background, I am very fixated to looping element-wise. I tried looking for something like chisq.test(x, p=p) of R, but that R function uses bins - 1 for df, so the df is off by the number of parameters estimated, and I have no idea how to use Octave's chisquare_test_homogeneity(x, y, c).

Comment: `cellfun` is only slightly more efficient than a for loop, it's not a vectorised operation. You can do it with a for loop if you prefer, this is just more efficient (but hopefully equally clear) syntax. It is typically not possible to vectorise when cell arrays are involved like this. The main point to note is that your `if` block was unnecessary, and you could have gotten away with a single for block, no need for an inner one.